# Django NoReverseMatch : Reverse for ‘entry’ not found. ‘login’ is not a valid view function or pattern

Tags: python-3.x, django, namespaces

I have a wiki application and I am trying to list entries in homepage(index) with namespacing urls but I am getting the reverse for 'entry' not found error for my view function called 'entry'.

**urls.py**

```
from . import views

app_name="wiki"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("<str:title>", views.entry, name="title")
]
```

**views.py**

```
from . import util

def index(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
        "entries": util.list_entries()
    })
def entry(request,title):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {"entry_title":title ,
        "entry_body": util.get_entry(title)})
```

**index.html**

```
{% block body %}
    <h1>All Pages</h1>

    <ul>
        {% for i in entries %}
            <li> <a href="{% url 'wiki:entry' i %}"> {{ i }} </a</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

If I change `wiki:entry` to `wiki:index` I can successfully generate list items and link all of them to homepage. Somehow `{% url 'wiki:entry' i %}` doesn't retrieve entry view at **views.py** and use `i` for the `title` . Also, if I hardcode url in the template like `href="{{i}}"` it does also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `<li> <a href="{% url 'wiki:entry' i %}"> {{ i }} </a</li>`  
 use             `<li> <a href="{% url 'wiki:title' i %}"> {{ i }} </a</li>`
since you are using "title" as your url name for the view "entry"